# The Conjugate Beta Prior proof

Tags: self-study, bayes, conjugate-prior, beta-distribution

[image: The Conjugate Beta Prior]

Hello.
I'm having a problem with trying to figure out this proof that shows the beta
distribution is conjugate to the binomial distribution (picture attached). 
I understand it until the third row, but I got confused with this step from the third to the fourth row.
I would appreciate a simple explanation.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To go from the third to fourth row just ignore factors that are constant with respect to $\pi$. That is, let

$$\binom{n}{y}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}=k$$

so

$$p(\pi|y)=k \cdot \pi^y (1-\pi)^{(n-y)}\pi^{(\alpha-1)}(1-\pi)^{(\beta-1)}$$

or

$$p(\pi|y) \propto \pi^y(1-\pi)^{(n-y)}\pi^{(\alpha-1)}(1-\pi)^{(\beta-1)}$$

The idea's to deal just with the kernel of the probability distribution, knowing you can always put the normalizing constant back in later.