# I'm not asking for a conjugate prior. Is there a distribution $p(x|y)$ that satisfies $\int p(x|y)Beta(y|a,b) dy = Beta(x| a', b')$?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I know the result of integrating a Gaussian against another Gaussian is still Gaussian, $$\int N(x|\mu_y,\sigma_y)N(y|\mu,\sigma) dy = N(x|\mu',\sigma')\quad.$$

Can I get the same form for Beta distributions? or is there a $p(x|y)$ that makes the result another Beta distribution? like
$$\int p(x|y)~\textrm{Beta}(y|a,b) dy = \textrm{Beta}(x| a', b')\quad.$$

Perhaps a Delta function centered at $y$ will do, $p(x|y)=\delta_y(x)$, so that the resulting Beta distribution stays the same, right? But what if I don't want all the mass at one point?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

**EDIT**
I'm not asking for a conjugate prior or likelihood function, if you suggest Binomial please at least add some explanation, it is not that obvious (to me).

**EDIT**
$$p(y|x)=\frac{p(x|y)p(y)}{p(x)}=\frac{p(x|y)p(y)}{\int p(x|y)p(y)dy}$$
AFAIK, we call $p(y)$ a conjugate prior for $p(x|y)$ if $p(y|x)$ stays the same form as $p(y)$. **But I want $p(x)$ to be in the same form as $p(y)$ instead.** I'm not quite familiar with statistics, are these the same thing?

**comments and corrections by Juho Kokkala** (thanks :)

> So this could be interpreted as 'If we have a Beta prior for parameter
>   $y$, what would be an observation model $p(x|y)p(x|y)$ so that the
>   prior predictive for $x$ is $\textrm{Beta}$ rather than 'what would be an
>   observation model so that the posterior for $y$ is $\textrm{Beta}$. Where the
>   latter would be answered with Binomial, but not the former.

> Note that the first claim about Gaussians does not hold if $\mu_y$,
>   $\sigma_y$ are some general functions of $y$ -- $\sigma_y$ must be a
>   constant and $\mu_y$ an affine function of $y$.

Comment: Binomial distribution.

Comment: @Greenparker I know Beta is the conjugate prior of Binomial, so I get a Beta based on $y$ inside the integration, but I not sure how is the integral still a Beta?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82897/the-conjugate-beta-prior-proof

Comment: @user777 I know how Beta is the conjugate prior of Binomial, but how is the integral still a Beta?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the beta distribution have a conjugate prior?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67443/does-the-beta-distribution-have-a-conjugate-prior)

Comment: The Binomial is not a conjugate prior for the Beta: rather, the Beta is the conjugate prior for the Binomial.  And that, it seems, is *precisely* what you are asking. One might say that this question is asking for a "conjugate posterior" for the Beta distribution.  As such, @greenparker nailed the answer.

Comment: @whuber Um, I don't see how this is asking for that. Note that the first factor of the integrand is supposed to be $p(x \mid y)$ and the outcome is desired to be a Beta density for $x$. So this could be interpreted as 'If we have a Beta prior for parameter $y$, what would be an observation model $p(x|y)$ so that the _prior predictive_ for $x$ is Beta' rather than 'what would be an observation model so that the posterior for $y$ is Beta'. Where the latter would be answered with Binomial, but not the former.

Comment: @dontloo Note that the first claim about Gaussians does not hold if $\mu_y,\sigma_y$ are some general functions of $y$ -- $\sigma_y$ must be a constant and $\mu_y$  an affine function of $y$.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala and so glad finally someone sees my point!

Comment: @whuber I don't think this quite fits the definition of conjugate prior or posterior, the integral should be a function of $x$ instead of $y$, perhaps you missed the integral sign?

Comment: One obvious solution is when $f(x|p)=Beta(x|a',b')$, i.e. when $x$ is independent of $p$.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks! just to clarify, if using the same notation as in the question, when $x$ is independent of $y$, then $p(x)=p(x|y)=Beta(x|a',b')$, right?

Comment: yes, indeed, I used the wrong notation.